# using the dreal function in fortran

Tags: fortran, complex-numbers

I have a complex(8) matrix A(-n:n,-m:m) in Fortran which has many elements practically zero, e.g 10e-8 etc. I want to make these small values equal to zero. I type:

```
do i=-n,n
    do j=-m,m
        if (dreal(A(i,j))<=cutoff) dreal(A(i,j))=0.0d0
        if (dimag(A(i,j))<=cutoff) dimag(A(i,j))=0.0d0
    end do
end do
```

where cutoff has been declared as a real(8) type with value 0.00000010d0, but I get errors:

```
 error #6512: A scalar-valued expression is required in this context.
 error #6408: This name has already been used as an intrinsic function name.   [DREAL]
 error #6515: This function, which is specified as the left side of an assignment statement, is invalid.   [DREAL]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

UPDATE:  @francescalus noted that this question has been asked before. 
According to the answer I change the code to:

```
 do i=-n,n
    do j=-m,m
    ar= A(i,j)%re; ai=A(i,j)%im; 
       if (ar <cutoff) A(i,j)%re=0.0d0
       if (ai<cutoff)  A(i,j)%im=0.0d0
    end do
end do
```

but I still get the first error:

```
error #6512: A scalar-valued expression is required in this context.
```

Comment: Further to the linked question: `dreal` returns the real part.  That real part isn't a variable to be set.  You need to find a way, such as `A(i,j)%re=0`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried:   
    ar= A(i,j)%re;
    if (ar <cutoff) A(i,j)%re=0.0d0    
but I still have the first error:     
    error #6512: A scalar-valued expression is required in this context.

Comment: Is `cutoff` an array or scalar?

Comment: cutoff is a real(8) number with value cutoff=0.0000010d0. I really don't get this error

Comment: Not an answer: you might like to try `where (A%re < cutoff) A%re = 0.0` and similarly for the imaginary part.

Comment: ar, ai are real(8) numbers, i.e scalars

Comment: just want to point out that `dreal(a)` is not in Fortran standard. The same behavior can be achieved with `real(a,kind=real64)` where `real64` is obtained from `use iso_fortran_env, only: real64`.

Comment: @francescalus my bad, with cutoff a scalar  it produces no errors and runs (I had declared cutoff as an array...)